# CMYK Lines and Fills in QGIS

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, you can apply CMYK to text, using the CMYK sliders palette. However, I can only find an RGB colour picker for lines and fills.

Is there a way to apply CMYK to these elements?

Comment: Sounds like a good "future project" for QGIS.

Comment: I second this...

Answer (score 2):

QGIS uses the operating system's default color picker with its features and limitations.
You'll have to convert the color codes.